# How do I keep a floating action button consistent across multiple activities?

Tags: android, performance

I am building an app that has a floating action button that opens a menu. I want to be able to keep the menu consistent without having to add it to every activity.

I'm thinking that I could simply create the MainActivity and place a ViewStub within a LinearLayout with the id "holder". Then, when a menu button is clicked, I'll just remove the view from the holder and add the new view.

Are there any pitfalls to this method?  Any suggestions on a better way?

Here's my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout holder;
    private ViewStub viewStub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        holder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.holder);

        viewStub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.viewStub);
        viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.content_main);
        viewStub.inflate();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch(id){
            case R.id.action_main:
                loadLayout(R.layout.content_main);
                break;
            case R.id.action_secondary:
                loadLayout(R.layout.content_secondary);
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void loadLayout(int layout){
        holder.removeAllViews();
        holder.addView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layout,holder,false));
    }
}
```

And here's my main layout where I load in my content layouts into the "holder":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.simplepopoutmenu.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/viewStub"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I may have just answered my own question. I have the context set in my layout files (ie content_secondary.xml has context set to SecondaryContentActivity), but the Activity code is not getting executed. Probably because the Activity is never started. I guess I'm putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: What exactly you eant to done by floating action button in all activities

Comment: So I have this app that has bunch of related activities. They all have a floating menu button on the bottom left that slides in a custom menu from the left. The button then turns into a close button which, you guessed it, closes the menu :)

I want to be able to create the menu and floating button once and have it persist on specific activities. I'm thinking that fragments might be the answer but I'm looking for suggestions from more seasoned developers.

Comment: You may create a base activity then extend that base activity for other activities so you will get it available in all activities

Comment: Simple solution. Thanks Umar Ata!